# kubernetes pod deployment not updating

Tags: kubernetes, makefile, kubernetes-pod, azure-container-registry, kubernetes-deployment

I have a pod `egress-operator-controller-manager` created from [makefile](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator/blob/master/Makefile) by command `make deploy IMG=my_azure_repo/egress-operator:v0.1`.
[image]

This pod was showing `unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized` error in description, so I created `imagePullSecrets` and trying to update this pod with secret by creating pod's deployment.yaml [`egress-operator-manager.yaml`] file. 
But when I am applying this yaml file its giving below error:

```
root@Ubuntu18-VM:~/egress-operator# kubectl apply -f /home/user/egress-operator-manager.yaml
The Deployment "egress-operator-controller-manager" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value:
 v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"moduleId":"egress-operator"}, 
MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable
```

***egress-operator-manager.yaml***

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: egress-operator-controller-manager
  namespace: egress-operator-system
  labels:
    moduleId: egress-operator
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      moduleId: egress-operator
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        moduleId: egress-operator
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: my_azure_repo/egress-operator:v0.1
          name: egress-operator
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: mysecret
```

Can somene let me know that how can I update this pod's deployment.yaml ?

Comment: what is the current configuration of this file as it is on your k8s cluster? the error message suggests that "[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}:" has been modified. the nil value probably indicates that this value is not available in your yaml file but on the currently applied config. most likely adding this value will then let you apply the new configuration

Comment: I am deploying this pod with "make deploy" command as mentioned in que, how can I find the deployment of existing pod ? Is there any kubectl command to get the existing deployment/configuration of running pod ?

Comment: yes there is. the command for getting the currently deployed version is "kubectl get deployment egress-operator-controller-manager -n egress-operator-system -o yaml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the deployment once and try applying the YAML agian.

it could be due to K8s service won't allow the **rolling update** once deployed the **label selectors** of **K8s service** can not be updated until you decide to delete the existing **deployment**

```
Changing selectors leads to undefined behaviors - users are not expected to change the selectors
```

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50808

Comment: What does "Delete the deployment" mean

Comment: kubectl delete deployment <deployment name>, remove your POD and redeploy editing label in rollingupdate is not possible